# Pandas resample raises type error for index consisting of datetime objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to resample a very simple dataframe, which fails with the following exception:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

I read the pandas API docs and looked at dozens of examples and  I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```py
# %%
import pandas as pd
print(f"pandas version: {pd.__version__}\n\n")

data = pd.DataFrame({"created": ['2019-03-07T11:01:07.361+0000',
                                 '2019-06-05T15:09:51.203+0100',
                                 '2019-06-05T15:09:51.203+0100'],
                     "value": [10, 20, 30]})

# %%
print(f"original type: {type(data.created[0])}\n")
data.info()

# %%
data.created = pd.to_datetime(data.created)

# %%
print(f"updated type: {type(data.created[0])}\n")
data.info()

# %%
data.set_index("created", inplace=True)
data.info()

# %%
data.resample("D").mean()
```

Here is the result

`pandas version: 0.24.2`

```
original type: <class 'str'>

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
created    3 non-null object
value      3 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 128.0+ bytes
```

```
updated type: <class 'datetime.datetime'>

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
created    3 non-null object
value      3 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 128.0+ bytes
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 3 entries, 2019-03-07 11:01:07.361000+00:00 to 2019-06-05 15:09:51.203000+01:00
Data columns (total 1 columns):
value    3 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 48.0+ bytes
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/me/dev/misc/index.py", line 32, in <module>
    data.resample("D").mean()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8155, in resample
    base=base, key=on, level=level)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1250, in resample
    return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1380, in _get_resampler
    "but got an instance of %r" % type(ax).__name__)
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'Index, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

Comment: Your index **looks** like a Datetime, but the values are all strings, so it's just a normal Index

Comment: `data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, utc=True)` fixes this

Comment: `data.index.dtype` returns object

Comment: @ALollz `utc=True` did the job. I was already calling `pd.to_datetime(data.created)` before I converted it into an index. Adding the utc parameter fixed it. However, I still do not understand why it is needed

Comment: I don't know, did you perhaps surpress some error or warning? You should get a `ValueError` without specifying `utc=True`, but if somewhere in you've tried to handle that error my guess is it went unnoticed and never really changed the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start from some principles:

1. To do a *resample*, the source *Series* or *DataFrame* must have e.g.
   a **DatetimeIndex** (not an "ordinary" index).
2. You could *set_index* to this column, but to do so, all *Datetime*
   elements must be in **the same** time zone (your data are not).

So you can proceed as follows:

1. While converting *created* column to *Datetime* (a part of your code),
   pass *utc=True* to "unify" the timezone:

   ```
   data.created = pd.to_datetime(data.created, utc=True)
   ```
2. Set the index and then you are free to resample:

   ```
   data.set_index('created').resample("D").mean()
   ```

Another option: Instead of *set_index*, you can pass *on* parameter,
specifying a Datetime(-like) column:

```
data.resample("D", on='created').mean()
```

but this column still has to have all entries in the same time zone.

Comment: Thanks, the same time zone requirement makes sense